# Not allowed to load local resource: When loading images from file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, fileserver

I have an App (angular) and API (.net core) and I have a shared folder on a data server with 20k images. I would like to display image as part of a search result. Sound simple, unfortunately I'm not able to do it because some security issues in Chrome. This is internal application.

So I have on the view:

```
<div *ngFor="let drawing of drawings">
    <img [src]="getPhotoURL(drawing.fileUrl)" height="300">
</div>
```

And the example image path looks like below:

> \\data-3\eng$\ItemsDrawings\RZ10006.jpg

and on the view backend - DomSanitizer to bypass Security:

```
getPhotoURL(url: string) {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

So the error I'm getting:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file://data-3/eng$/ItemsDrawings\RZ10006.jpg

I found that this is related to Chrome not allowing to access local files, which is understandable, but this is actually a data server.
I've seen lot's of workaround how to pass bypass this in Chrome but I'm not going to make changes to Chrome for each user.

I know I can load image to API and then pass it to the front end, but just wondering if this is the only option here?

Could anyone put some light on the subject please?

I got full access to the data server if there are any configuration that need to be done.

Comment: Why you dont put the image in wwwroot folder of asp.net core server or assets folder of angular project ?

Comment: because I have 20,000 images and I would prefer to have images on dedicated data storage. But I’m considering this option.